# Merging and removing elements from list in a loop

Tags: python, list, merge

I would like to do such thing:

I have a list :

```
  pairs =  [1,1,1,1,0,0,2,2,2,2,0,3,3,3,3,0,0,0,0,0,4,4,4,4]
```

I found there elements:

```
  frags =   [[1,1,1,1],[2,2,2,2],[3,3,3,3],[4,4,4,4]]
```

And now I want to incorporate blocks of 0s that are shorter than 4:

```
[[1,1,1,1,0,0,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3],[4,4,4,4]]
```

I've tried to do it this way:

```
        while j < len(frags)-1:    # I added a 'terminator' before, so that len-1           
            stop_1 = pairs.index(frags[j][-1])
            start_1 = pairs.index(frags[j][0])
            start_2 = pairs.index(frags[j+1][0])
            stop_2 = pairs.index(frags[j+1][-1])
            island = float(start_2 - stop_1 - 1)
            if island < 4 :  
                frags[j] = pairs[start_1:stop_2+1]
                frags.remove(frags[j+1]) #the same iteration again
            else: j+=1
```

But if I remove them, I get the infinite loop because frag gets shorter than len forever. 
How can I solve it?

Comment: Shouldn't there be a `0` between `2` and `3` in the expected output? `[1,1,1,1,0,0,2,2,2,2,0,3,3,3,3]`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `itertools.groupby`, like this

```
from itertools import groupby

groups, temp = [], []
# Group items based on the actual values
for key, grp in groupby(pairs):
    grp = list(grp)
    # If it is a group of zeros and the size is >= 4
    if key == 0 and len(grp) >= 4:
        # Add the accumulated groups to the result
        groups.append(temp)
        # Make the accumulator free
        temp = []
    else:
        # If it is a group of non-zeros or zeros of size < 4,
        # extend the accumulated group
        temp.extend(grp)

if temp:
    groups.append(temp)

print(groups)
# [[1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 3, 3, 3, 3], [4, 4, 4, 4]]
```

Comment: Do you think I can make a global copy of frags as a 'loop scope' (while j < len(global_copy)-1) and inside loop remove elements from the frags and the copy at the same time, so the 'loop scope' will be updated?

Comment: Note that this'll produce an empty list as the first element if `pairs` starts with four or more zeros. i.e. `[0,0,0,0]` -> `[[]]`. Also, here's the [relevant link to groupby](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby).